# Delete file on realtime Database on Firebase with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the database link

```
const firebase = "https://booktakeaway-dd150-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app"
```

And this the function that i use to delete the file, but i doesn't work. I can't find anything online.

```
return async dispatch => {
    try {
      const response = await firebase.get(`booksData.json?auth=${token}`);
      const firebaseData= response.data;
      for (let key in dataFirebase) {
        if (id === firebaseData[key].bookId) {
          await firebase.ref(`/booksData/${key}`).remove();
          console.log("Done");
        }
      }
      await dispatch(getSavedBooksIDs());
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

[image: Structure of the databse]

Comment: What is the `firebase` variable you use in the second code snippet? It doesn't seem to be the same as in the first code snippet (despite the name), but it also doesn't look like any SDK/library I know of.

Comment: Yes, is the same but is imported from another component, i used that so many time for read and add some files

Comment: I might be missing something basic here, but how are you calling `get()` and `ref()` on a string?

Comment: I'm a beginner, i'm sorry, maybe i use ref on a wrong way, how should i do?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to use here. The second snippet seems partially try to use the Firebase SDK with this `firebase.ref(`/booksData/${key}`).remove()`. But the `await firebase.get(`booksData.json?auth=${token}`)` then seems to be the REST API, as does the `const firebase = "https://booktakeaway-dd150-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app"` first snippet. It's hard to help with we don't know which API/SDK you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set it to null, worked for me:

```
return async dispatch => {
    try {
      const response = await firebase.get(`booksData.json?auth=${token}`);
      const firebaseData= response.data;
      for (let key in firebaseData) {
        if (id === firebaseData[key].bookId) {
          await firebase.ref(`booksData/${key}`).set(null);
          console.log("Done");
        }
      }
      await dispatch(getSavedBooksIDs());
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Not for me: Request failed with status code 401

Comment: Maybe i use ref on a wrong way, how should i do?

Comment: I'll send you a snippet of my code in a few minutes

Comment: My apologies, set it to null explicitly: `    firebase.ref(path).set(null).then(callback()).catch();`

Comment: May I ask, do you get any data when querying the database with `booksData.json?auth=${token}`?

Comment: I only take the key of the file

Comment: ```await firebase.ref(`/booksData/${key}`).set(null);``` like this?

Comment: sorry, you should remove the first '/' like so: `await firebase.ref(\`booksData/${key}\`).set(null);`